# Динамические события

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Работаю на Дельфи.
Нужно организовать такую логику:

скажем, на форме есть куча radiobutton-ов, и хочется, чтобы при выборе их обрабатывалась только одна и та же процедура/функция.

Примерно так:

```
procedure someprocedure;
begin
writeLog('was clicked'+self.name);
end;
procedure formCreate;
begin
..........
for i:=1 to 99 do 
radiobutton[i].onclick:=someFunction()/someProcedure;
..........
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот такой вариант пойдёт?:

Есть массив a: array [1..100] of TRadioButton;
На FormCreate они создаются, ну или массив заполняется ссылками на уже существующие объекты.

В описании формы добавляешь нужную процедуру, вот тут:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
{--->}procedure SomeProcedure(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Далее в коде после слова implementation
пишешь:

```
procedure TForm1.SomeProcedure(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {что-то делаешь...
  Sender здесь - объект который вызывает,
  Если точно знаешь что он TRadioButton, и хочешь получить доступ к его полям пишешь:
  (Sender as TRadioButton).свойство
}
end;
```

Теперь задаёшь всем объектам эту процедуру на нажатие
for i:=0 to 99 do 
a[i].onClick:=SomeProcedure;

Ну вроде всё, что тут ещё рассказывать...